# why I get "not supported yet" exception in j2me in send receive sms?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-7, wma

I try to send and receive sms in j2me but when Netbeans suggest method for me it also adds an exception in it:

```
 ms.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

     public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection mc) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
     }
 });
```

I nearly sure that j2me WMA support this method. So what is the problem that Netbeans throw this exception?

Comment: NetBeans is just creating a template for you to edit, you can have your own implementation in the place of unsupported exception.

Comment: oh.i think that my question was so silly!thank you.make an answer for choose as best answer if you want.thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans is just creating a template for you to edit, you can have your own implementation in the place of unsupported exception.

Answer (score 1):

The netbeans generator puts it in so you can change it to do what you want to do there. If you forget to change it, the exception will remind you.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a reminder by NetBeans that you need to provide its implementation.